# Angular multiple http post requests give me error: "net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES"

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I am importing an .xlsx file, which has 6000 customers inside and I am trying to loop throught customers and make an `http post` request foreach customer, but I get this error:

> net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES.

How can I insert these customers? They need to be passed throught my backend in order to get encrypted.

```
this.customers.forEach(customer => {
   this.customerService
     .createCustomer(customer)
     .pipe(take(1))
     .subscribe(() => {});
});
```

Only 2000 customers are imported. Any way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Change post to take an array.  1 post = 6000 customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know by the way i am not 100% sure but the browser especially Chrome can't handle a very large number of requests in a short period of time,

And to solve this just try to make a bit delay after `2000` request as you mentioned that this number could be handled.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I run the angular project in firefox, and worked perfectly. I just had to click "wait" when the page started to lag, and after that "continue script" when an alert showed.