# How to handle multiple post request on angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm using Angular 12 and NestJS and I need to insert about 3000 items in a synchronization process where I get these items from an external API and register or update them in my application's database. When I try to submit the request, I get a lot of issues like high memory usage, browser freezes, and I get **ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES** error in Chrome and only a few items are entered.

**My component:**

```
this.items.forEach((item) => {
  this.itemService.insert(item).subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(res);
  })
})
```

**My service:**

```
insert(item: Item): Observable<Item> {
return this.http.post<Item>(`${APIURL}/item`);
}
```

I tried using forkJoin, but I had the same problem. My goal is to insert or update items without crashes and if possible to follow the progress, for example "500 out of 3000 synchronized..."

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/q/56892378/5468463?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause come from Javascript asynchronous, that mean you push 3000 items almost same time then Chrome will throw this error.

To solve the issue, we should reduce the amount request with below solutions:

- Solution 1: Reduce number request in amount of time.
- Solution 2: Refine your API that able to update multiple items at same time (For example write data with Bulk Write in Mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)

To make it simple, I use solution 1, it didn't efficent than solution 2 but it more simple.

Solution 1: Use `concatMap` in RxJs for waiting each request done as example below

```
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

from(items)
  .pipe(concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(1000))))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Then you can replace `of(item).pipe(delay(1000)))` with your `instert(item)` post request.

Live demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-uamv8w?file=index.ts

Comment: Please do not answer on duplicate questions

Comment: Thanks for help me know the rule. I'm new here. But what should I do when I though the answear on older duplicated is not good enough and it was accepted? I just want to contribue to community in the right way.